# Is it theoretically reasonable to use CNN for data like categorical and numeric data?

Tags: deep-learning, classification, theory, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to use CNN to do a binary classification.
As CNN shows its strength in feature extraction, it has been many uses for pattern data like image and voice.
However, the dataset I have is not image or voice data, but categorical data and numerical data, which are different from this case.
My question is as follows.

1. In this situation,  Is it theoretically reasonable to use CNN for data in this configuration?
2. If it is reasonable, would it be reasonable to artificially place my dataset in a two-dimensional form and perform a 2D-CNN?

I often see examples of using CNN in many classifiers through Kaggle and various media, and I can see not only images and voices, but also numerical and categorical data like mine.
I really wonder this is theoretically a problem, and I would appreciate it if you could recommend it if you knew about the related paper or research.

I'm looking forward to hearing any advice about this situation. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

CNNs for images apply kernels to neighboring pixels and blocks of image. CNNs for audio work on spectrograms, i.e. use input data proximity as well.

If your data inputs has some sort of closeness (e.g. time-series, graph...), then CNN might be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think my data inputs doesn't have some sort of closeness... I already tried CNN for my data, it is slightly better than ANN and DNN. In this case, Should I call it a coincidence?

Comment: I can only imagine how you setup your experiments, but I think you can achieve even better results by experimenting with multi-layer fully-connected networks.

Comment: I used CNN for binary text classification and got 80% accuracy with 64% F1 score. So, I think we can use them.

Comment: @Raghvendra, the question is about tabular data, not textual